# comparing vs equating coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two linear equations

```
 Ax + By + C = 0

 ax + by + c = 0
```

Now if i proceed in the following way :

```
  Ax + By + C = ax + by + c    ( Since both are equal to zero )
 (A-a)x + (B-b)y + (C-c) = 0
 (A-a)x + (B-b)y + (C-c) = 0x + 0y + 0
```

which will lead me to A = a ; B = b ; C = C; assuming non-zero vlues for *x* and *y* which is clearly wrong.

My question is why is the above wrong , and could you please clarify what does one mean by comparing coefficients and equating them ?

Comment: i would one equation solving e.g. for $x$ and plug this in the other one

Comment: two planes can be identical , parallel or they cut each other in a straight line

Answer (score 1):

The big problem here, as I see it, is that you aren't entirely clear on what the equations say. Do they say that

- $A, B, C, a, b, c$ are such that the equations are true for any $x, y, z$?
- $A, B, C, a, b, c$ are fixed (although possibly unknown) and we limit ourselves to values of $x, y, z$ such that both equations are satisfied simultaneously?
- $A, B, C, a, b, c$ are fixed (although possibly unknown) and we study the set of $x, y, z$ which satisfy the first equation and the set of $x, y, z$ which satisfy the second equation and see in what way we may compare the two?
- something else?

How to correctly treat the two equations will depend greatly on *what they mean*, and until that is clear you can't really put them togeher in any way.

Comment: Ahh... i see...so what you’re saying is that we treat equations on how we interpret them or rather what particular problem we are focusing on. Usually in textbooks implicitly change context without making clear what the focus is ... maybe that lead me to mix them up. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @SaitamaSensei What the different letters in an equation means is usually implicit from the context of the problem. But without that there is no way to know what a given equation or a set of equations really means, and thus what to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

There is not contradiction in your result indeed the following

$$  (A-a)x + (B-b)y + (C-c) = 0$$

is always true for every x and y if and only if the two lines coincides that is $A=a$, $B=b$,$C=c$.

Otherwise you can obtain x or y by one equation, sustitute in the other and find the intersection point.

Comment: That makes it more clear in lieu of the first response. Arigato :)

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$(3-2)x+(4-3)y+(6-5)=0 \\ \implies x + y + 1 = 0$$This equations holds true for all values of $x$ and $y$ at a certain line on 2D plane. So it the coefficients can be something other than $0$ and the equation will still hold.

If you say that equation $$ax+by+c=0$$ holds for all values of $x$ and $y$, then the coefficients have to be zero. But if that isn't the case you can have non-zero coefficients.